# PE File Format Section Add On

Tags: c++, c, file, format, portable-executable

I'm confused on why they use - 1 here. Can someone explain what this line is doing in very very very very low level detail please... Not o its subtracting 1 structure.... I need to know more...about the low level... thanks...

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER last_section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nt_headers) + (nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1);
```

The code above is in the below function:

```
//Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/inject2exe.aspx
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER add_section(const char *section_name, unsigned int section_size, void *image_addr) {
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)image_addr;
    if(dos_header->e_magic != 0x5A4D) {
        wprintf(L"Could not retrieve DOS header from %p", image_addr);
        return NULL;
    }
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_headers = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)dos_header + dos_header->e_lfanew);
    if(nt_headers->OptionalHeader.Magic != 0x010B) {
        wprintf(L"Could not retrieve NT header from %p", dos_header);
        return NULL;
    }
    const int name_max_length = 8;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER last_section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nt_headers) + (nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1);
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER new_section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nt_headers) + (nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
    memset(new_section, 0, sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
    new_section->Characteristics = IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE | IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE;
    memcpy(new_section->Name, section_name, name_max_length);
    new_section->Misc.VirtualSize = section_size;
    new_section->PointerToRawData = align_to_boundary(last_section->PointerToRawData + last_section->SizeOfRawData,
        nt_headers->OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
    new_section->SizeOfRawData = align_to_boundary(section_size, nt_headers->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
    new_section->VirtualAddress = align_to_boundary(last_section->VirtualAddress + last_section->Misc.VirtualSize,
        nt_headers->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
    nt_headers->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage =  new_section->VirtualAddress + new_section->Misc.VirtualSize;
    nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections++;
    return new_section;
}
```

Comment: To get the last section, you need to go to the first section plus number of sections minus one. For example, if there is only one section, that is also the last one and you have to add zero. If there are two sections, the last section is the first plus one.

Comment: Because the arrays are indexed starting at zero. Last element's index is `count - 1`. `last_section` is a pointer to the last existing section, `new_section` is a pointer to where the next one will go (though I don't see how it makes sure it is addressing valid memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++, array elements are indexed from `0` to `n-1` (in FORTRAN from `1` to `n`). So, if you have a pointer `p0` to the first element but want a pointer to the last element you have to add `n-1`:
`plast=p0+n-1`. This all there is to this.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the time you took to respond. I was looking for a visual coded example as an answer. Which I don't think I'm going to get. Using the PE file structures above. Its hard to visually see things in memory like you would in construction. I like to see what I'm building in construction but I can't do this in programming. It makes learning hard for me.